# Sql Server - How do I query a geography column based on Lat/Long min max

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlgeography

I have a table with a geography column that stores the location of a property.

I have a procedure something like this -

```
PROCEDURE dbo.spt_sold_property_search
(
@latitude_min   Decimal(9,6),
@latitude_max   Decimal(9,6),
@longitude_max  Decimal(9,6),
@longitude_min  Decimal(9,6)
)

AS BEGIN    

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sold_property] AS p WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE p.location ***is in the lat/long min max bounds***

END
```

What would I need in the where clause to check if the geography point is in the bounds of the Lat/Long min max? It is an large dataset so performance is a critical.

Should I be creating a Geography SQL type in code from the bounds and pass that into the proc as a procedure?

I was also considering creating 2 calculated int columns (lat/long) which would be created on insert, and then simple <  > as I heard that is faster than Geography queries.

Comment: why don't you try those 2 approaches?

Comment: "What would I need in the where clause to check if the geography point is in the bounds of the Lat/Long min max?"   - that is my question, I don't know what the where statement would be to try it...

Comment: got it..what does data in `location` column look like?

Comment: It is the SQL-server Geography data type.

Comment: I have no experience with `geography`, but a quick look online suggests that you need to convert your co-ordinates into a `polygon` `geography` then use `.STWithin` for the test. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929207.aspx and also http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only require the latitude and the longitude to be within the max/min values then use the [Lat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933806.aspx) and Long properties:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sold_property] AS p WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE p.location.Lat BETWEEN @latitude_min and @latitude_max
  AND p.location.Long BETWEEN @longitude_min and @longitude_max
```

However, in my opinion it will be correctly to construct a polygon from the provided coordinates and then use the [STWithin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929207.aspx) method to check if the point in the table is within the polygon, like this:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::Parse('POLYGON (('+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@latitude_min)+', '+
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@latitude_max)+', '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@longitude_min)+', '+
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),@longitude_max)+'))');

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sold_property] AS p WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE @g.STWithin(p.location)
```

Please note that the latter query maybe not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). As Ben Thul mentioned below the spatial indexes may support the `STWithin`

Comment: In re: SARGability, spatial indexes support `STWithin`. From the docs: "Spatial indexes support the following set-oriented geometry methods under certain conditions: STContains(), STDistance(), STEquals(), STIntersects(), STOverlaps(), STTouches(), and STWithin()".